# How to render Gidview widget when snapshot.hasData is done

Tags: flutter, dart

I found error when I try to render return from json in Gridview. All the stuff is done. Call api, using provider state is done. Everything is done and I got print my api return is success with return all data.

But I failed to render this data to my layout.

Here is the error

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the vertical direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.


════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#522de relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Column 
lib\…\real\promo_product.dart:119
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The method '>' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >(1e-10)
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Column 
lib\…\real\promo_product.dart:127
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I use `FutureBuilder` but when `snapshot.hasData` has come, I failed to render.

This is my code

```
class PromoProduct extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PromoProductState createState() => _PromoProductState();
}

class _PromoProductState extends State<PromoProduct> {
  DateTime time = DateTime.now();
  bool _disposed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      if (!_disposed)
        setState(() {
          time = time.add(Duration(seconds: -1));
        });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _disposed = true;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var product = Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context, listen: false);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        FutureBuilder<ProductModel>(
          future: product.getProducts(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemExtent: 130,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 15,
                            vertical: 15,
                          ),
                          itemCount: 7,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) => CustomCard(
                            title:
                                snapshot.data.data[index].product.productName,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text("Snapshot error"),
                );
              }
            } else {
              return CircularProgIndicator(
                paddingTop: 50.0,
                paddingBottom: 80.0,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

My card.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final title;

  CustomCard({this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 10,
                  horizontal: 10,
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Image.asset("assets/food.png"),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Text(
                      title,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.access_time,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          "15 Minutes",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.calendar_today,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          "Ready",
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My json output from api is good

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "id_outlet": 1,
            "id_product": 18,
            "created_at": "2020-04-14",
            "updated_at": "2020-04-14",
            "product": {
                "id": 18,
                "id_category": 2,
                "product_uuid": "9129d7b3-d5fe-32f2-9d61-e0ced6ead09b",
                "product_name": "UMBFJMXCKLV",
                "product_desc": "Ea saepe nihil itaque cumque quis cumque sed illo.",
                "product_amount": 89927,
                "product_image": "cooking-2132874_640.jpg",
                "product_status": "active",
                "product_recomended": "no",
                "product_new_arrived": "no",
                "discount": 2,
                "created_at": "2020-04-17",
                "updated_at": "2020-04-17"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "id_outlet": 1,
            "id_product": 4,
            "created_at": "2020-04-14",
            "updated_at": "2020-04-14",
            "product": {
                "id": 4,
                "id_category": 1,
                "product_uuid": "6195e061-7351-3500-8c87-a918ed1c4e2a",
                "product_name": "QWVWRIQO",
                "product_desc": "Id dolorem qui culpa.",
                "product_amount": 32752,
                "product_image": "pizza-3007395_640.jpg",
                "product_status": "active",
                "product_recomended": "no",
                "product_new_arrived": "no",
                "discount": null,
                "created_at": "2020-04-17",
                "updated_at": "2020-04-17"
            }
        },
    ],
    "error": null,
    "message": null,
    "code": 200
}
```

But why I failed when start from `if (snapshot.hasData) {}` try to build `ListView.builder` and call `itemBuilder: (context, index) => CustomCard()` ?

I'm stuck

Comment: Write shrinkWrap: true in ListView.builder of  PromoProduct class

Comment: Still error when I added `shrinkWrap: true`